# Using generate_series in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I have a table with data and I want to fill the date gaps with generate_series with PostgreSQL but I can't solve it. How can I join my table to the generate_series result? My attempt is the following:

```
SELECT series AS time,
       data 
FROM generate_series('2012-11-11', '2012-11-12', '2 minutes'::interval) AS series
LEFT JOIN data_table ON data_table.time = series
```

In this date range the result is:

```
               TIME             DATA
        2012.11.11. 13:00:06 | data 1
        2012.11.11. 13:08:06 | data 2
```

My aim would be similar like this:

```
            TIME            DATA
    2012.11.11. 13:00:06 | data 1
    2012.11.11. 13:02:06 | NULL
    2012.11.11. 13:06:06 | NULL
    2012.11.11. 13:08:06 | data 2 
    2012.11.11. 13:10:06 | NULL
    2012.11.11. 13:12:06 | NULL
    ...
```

Ergo the the whole table fill with time rows with 2 minutes interval. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your query should work.  I would give the value a column name:

```
SELECT g.series AS time, t.data 
FROM generate_series('2012-11-11', '2012-11-12', '2 minutes'::interval) AS g(series) LEFT JOIN
      data_table t
      ON t.time = g.series;
```